# Using fwrite without calling fflush or writing to stderr first

Tags: c, fwrite, stderr, printf, fflush

I have a function which writes binary data to a file or `stdout`. However the call to `fwrite()` sometimes fails, UNLESS I `fflush(stderr)` or print a report to `stderr` before attempting to `fwrite`.

Is this normal behaviour, or indicative of some underlying memory problem? It's difficult to debug because as soon as I `fprint` to `stderr` the data I'm trying to `fwrite` to `stdout`, the "problem" disappears.

Here's a very simplified version of the function.

```
int writebinary(FILE *fpout, void *data, long ntowrite) {

    long i; 

    /* lets say we know the input data is double float */
    double *p = data; 

    /* including this test line makes the function work! */
    for(i=0; i<ntowrite;i++) fprintf(stderr,"data[%d]=%g\n",i,p[i]);

    /* attempt to write data[] as a single block of bytes */
    m= fwrite(data,(size_t)(ntowrite*sizeof(double)),1,fpout);

    if(m!=1) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Write error: %d\n",ferror(fpout));
        return(-1); 
    }
    else return(m);
}
```

Any wisdom appreciated :)

Comment: Do you have any example code?

Comment: Providing any example code makes our work easy

Comment: it's embedded in some very complicated code - was hoping to spare you the details - let me check the errno first....

Comment: I saw a program that crashed unless you enable logging. It turned out that the logging library used a semaphore, preventing a race condition between two threads. `stderr` writes happen synchronously, so your code may be in a similar situation.

Comment: ferror(fpout) returns null, so no help there!

Comment: If the original program is multithreaded I'd look in the direction *dasblinkenlight* pointed too. Extensive (relativly slow) logging significantly influences the app's timing. And could lead to a classical Heisenbug. So a race is suddenly won by the one meant to win.

Comment: OT: Wouldn't `... = fwrite(data, sizeof(double), (size_t) ntowrite, fpout);` be more straight forward?

Comment: No multi-threading but repeated calls because the contents of the array pointed to by *data changes with time. @alk, thanks for pointing out the errno issue, but as for fwrite-ing a single block of bytes, there are reasons :)

Comment: @alk Thanks, hadn't realised that.  I'll delete my original comment

Comment: 1. You report "call to fwrite() sometimes fails".  What is the failure evidence?  What is `errno`? 2. Maybe try `fflush(fpout)` before/after `fwrite()` - `fflush(stdout)` may be a side effect of `fprintf(stderr...` 3. Is the value of `ntowrite` _large_ (for your system)?

Comment: @chux: Just deleted my hint, that `fwrite()` does not set `error`.

Comment: Sorry to repeat: what is the evidence of the failure?

Comment: @chux, the variable "m" returns zero, instead of 1, indicating failure to write the block of bytes. This seems to be a bit of a cryptic one for everyone - if there's nothing really obvious I may have to put it down to a peculiarity, stick to flushing stderr, and remove the question :) - but it would be nice to understand what might be happening.

Comment: Suggest calling `clearerr(fpout)` instead of `fprintf(stderr` and calling `fflush(fpout)` after the `fwrite(...fpout)`.  I think you have a error on stdout (or stderr) - from _something_, that `fprintf(stderr` is clearing.  You could check ferror(fpout) _before_ writing.  BTW: "ferror(fpout) returns null": maybe you mean "ferror(fpout) returns 0".

Answer (score 0):

This is not normal behavior.
Recommend the following.  There are a number of things in the posting which are of concern (see far below) but do not point to the problem - but *something* is wrong.

```
int writebinary2(FILE *fpout, void *data, long ntowrite) {
  size_t n = (size_t) ntowrite;
  double *dp = (double *) data;
  // pedantic checks
  if ((!fpout) || (!data) || (dp != data) || (ntowrite <= 0) || (n != ntowrite)) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Bad parameter\n");
    return(0);
  }
  clearerr(stderr);  // only needed for debug
  clearerr(fpout);
  /* attempt to write blocks of doubles */
  size_t m = fwrite(dp, sizeof(double), n, fpout);
  if (m != n) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Write error: %d\n",ferror(fpout));
    clearerr(fpout);
    return(-1);
  }
  if (fflush(fpout)) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Flush error: %d\n",ferror(fpout));
    clearerr(fpout);
    return(-1);
  }
  return(1);
}
```

1. ntowrite s/b size_t, an unsigned integer.  ntowrite = 0 may cause confusion on m.  ntowrite < 0 *will* cause issues.
2. m is not declared, assumed size_t.
3. format "data[%d]=%g\n" s/b "data[%ld]=%g\n"
4. i s/b size_t.
5. `(size_t)(ntowrite*sizeof(double))` s/b `((size_t)ntowrite)*sizeof(double)`.  See #7.
6. `fprintf(stderr...` should not be needed.  That is *the* question.
7. `fwrite(..., size, n ...)` works even if  `size * n` overflow.  So safer than OP.